# Adding multiple markers on Map from json data android

Tags: java, android

My Json data :

```
{
    "customer": [
        {
            "CustomerRequestId": 30,
            "CustomerId": 24,
            "CustomerName": "Saravanan",
            "Phonenumber": "9095897331",
            "PickupLat": "13.0667902",
            "PickupLng": "80.2458975",
            "DropLat": "13.0824243",
            "DropLng": "80.27546889999999",
            "FromLoc": "19-22, College Rd, Subba Road Avenue, Nungambakkam, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600006, India",
            "ToLoc": "Station Rd, Kannappar Thidal, Periyamet, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600003, India"
        },
        {
            "CustomerRequestId": 29,
            "CustomerId": 4,
            "CustomerName": "driver",
            "Phonenumber": "9876543210",
            "PickupLat": "13.0667902",
            "PickupLng": "80.2458975",
            "DropLat": "11.5432364",
            "DropLng": "79.47601329999999",
            "FromLoc": "19-22, College Rd, Subba Road Avenue, Nungambakkam, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600006, India",
            "ToLoc": "Nanthanar Nagar, Neyveli, Tamil Nadu 607802, India"
        },
        {
            "CustomerRequestId": 31,
            "CustomerId": 24,
            "CustomerName": "Saravanan",
            "Phonenumber": "9095897331",
            "PickupLat": "13.0654988",
            "PickupLng": "80.2432399",
            "DropLat": "12.9234492",
            "DropLng": "80.1587694",
            "FromLoc": "Gee Gee Emerald Towers, Sterling Rd, Seetha Nagar, Nungambakkam, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600034, India",
            "ToLoc": "231, Velachery Tambaram Main Rd, Durga Colony, Sembakkam, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600073, India"
        },
        {
            "CustomerRequestId": 28,
            "CustomerId": 1,
            "CustomerName": "aravind",
            "Phonenumber": "1234567890",
            "PickupLat": "13.056979199999997",
            "PickupLng": "80.2487355",
            "DropLat": "11.7465352",
            "DropLng": "79.7555841",
            "FromLoc": "27/14, Nungambakkam High Rd, Tirumurthy Nagar, Nungambakkam, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600034, India",
            "ToLoc": "79, Lawrence Rd, Market Colony, Thirupapuliyur, Cuddalore, Tamil Nadu 607002, India"
        },
        {
            "CustomerRequestId": 32,
            "CustomerId": 21,
            "CustomerName": "raja",
            "Phonenumber": "2012356489",
            "PickupLat": "13.0654969",
            "PickupLng": "80.2432014",
            "DropLat": "10.7904833",
            "DropLng": "78.7046725",
            "FromLoc": "Gee Gee Emerald Towers, Sterling Rd, Seetha Nagar, Nungambakkam, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600034, India",
            "ToLoc": "Chennai - Villupuram - Trichy - Kanyakumari Rd, Hanifa Colony, Railway Colony, Tiruchirappalli, Tamil Nadu 620020, India"
        },
        {
            "CustomerRequestId": 33,
            "CustomerId": 25,
            "CustomerName": "prabu",
            "Phonenumber": "9095897331",
            "PickupLat": "13.0654359",
            "PickupLng": "80.2441922",
            "DropLat": "12.923290699999999",
            "DropLng": "80.1599004",
            "FromLoc": "68/75-79, Subba Road Avenue, Nungambakkam, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600034, India",
            "ToLoc": "231, Velachery Tambaram Main Rd, Durga Colony, Sembakkam, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600073, India"
        }
    ]
}
```

Need to fetch all the Pickup Latitude Longitude and place markers on Map. Can anyone help me with this? I was able to fetch all the data and view it on the activity. But I was not able to add markers on the Map.)

```
private ArrayList<CustomerRequestList> dataList;
   Activity thisActivity;
   Context context;
   ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getRetrofit().create(ApiInterface.class);

    public CustomerListAdapter(ArrayList<CustomerRequestList> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_driver_request_list, parent, false);
        return new CustomerViewHolder(view);   
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomerViewHolder holder, int position) {                    holder.txtCusName.setText(dataList.get(position).getCustomerName());
        holder.txtCusPhon.setText(dataList.get(position).getPhonenumber()); 
        holder.txtCusFrom.setText(dataList.get(position).getFromLoc());
        holder.txtCusTo.setText(dataList.get(position).getToLoc());    
        String FromLat = dataList.get(position).getPickupLat();
        String FromLng = dataList.get(position).getPickupLng();
        String DropLat = dataList.get(position).getDropLat();
        String DropLng = dataList.get(position).getDropLng();            
        Utilities.printV("CustomerLoginResponse===>", FromLat);
        Utilities.printV("CustomerLoginResponse===>", FromLng);
        Utilities.printV("CustomerLoginResponse===>", DropLat);
        Utilities.printV("CustomerLoginResponse===>", DropLng);  
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    class CustomerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView txtCusName, txtCusFrom, txtCusPhon, txtCusTo;

        CustomerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtCusName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_Customer_Name);
            txtCusPhon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Customer_phonenumber);
            txtCusFrom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Customer_PickLocation);
            txtCusTo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Customer_DropLocation);
        }
    }
```

(Please help me to add multiple markers on the map for getting all the json data)

Comment: Did you tried anything for this?

Comment: Why are you showing your `RecyclerView`?  If you want to add markers to the Map, then you need to show your map activity

Comment: Yes, I was able to get the json data and show the data on the RecyclerView. I need to place marker on the map when the driver select a particular customer.